# Android format value currency when user type number on EditText

Tags: android

I am trying format a value entered in an `EditText`, this must happen immediately, i.e as soon as the user enters value into the `EditText`, the application must format the value and set it to the `EditText` again. My code is not correct and i can't find any way to format number on time

```
transfer_amount.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int start, int count, int after) {
    }
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
    }
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable charSequence) {
        if (charSequence.toString().length() == 1 && charSequence.toString().equals("0")) {
            transfer_amount.setText("");
        } else if (charSequence.toString().length() > 0 && (int) charSequence.toString().charAt(0) >= 48 && (int) charSequence.toString().charAt(0) <= 57) {
            Locale swedish = new Locale("sv", "SE");
            NumberFormat swedishFormat = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(swedish);
            transfer_amount.setText(swedishFormat.format(Long.parseLong((charSequence.toString()))));
        }
    }
});
```

## UPDATE

```
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    long enteredNumber = Long.parseLong(s.toString().replace(",", ""));
    transfer_amount.removeTextChangedListener(this);
    DecimalFormat formatter           = new DecimalFormat("#,###,###");
    String        yourFormattedString = formatter.format(enteredNumber);
    Log.e("yourFormattedString ", yourFormattedString);
    transfer_amount.setText(yourFormattedString);
    transfer_amount.addTextChangedListener(this);
}
```

this code work until format number, when formatted my EditText cleared and i dont know whats problem,

My Log:

```
E/yourFormattedString: 1
E/yourFormattedString: 11
E/yourFormattedString: 111
E/yourFormattedString: 1,111
E/yourFormattedString: 1
```

Comment: why condition && (int) charSequence.toString().charAt(0) >= 48 && (int) charSequence.toString().charAt(0) <= 57, Please explain. In place of Long.parseLong((charSequence.toString())) I used Double and its working fine but for different locale.

Comment: @Ramit limitation to between `0` and `9`

Comment: Ok, I got one problem. You are setting text in afterTextChanged so it will call again afterTextChanged. I am not sure currency symbol will add in start or end for mentioned currency. Please follow @Shabbir answer to remove textwatcher first and then add it again to prevent unnecessary call of text change

Answer (score 1):

For text change runtime you need to take care about the original string and modified string.

```
tt = new TextWatcher() {
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if(s.length()!=0) {
                long enteredNumber = Long.parseLong(s.toString().replace(",", ""));
                nameEdit.removeTextChangedListener(this);
                DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#,###,###");
                String yourFormattedString = formatter.format(enteredNumber);
                Log.e("yourFormattedString ", yourFormattedString);
                nameEdit.setText(yourFormattedString);
                nameEdit.addTextChangedListener(this);
                nameEdit.setSelection(yourFormattedString.length());
            }
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }
    };
    nameEdit.addTextChangedListener(tt);
```

Comment: after format value, cause of my `edittext` cleared, my post updated

Comment: does it printing LOG

Comment: post upadted with Logcat result

Comment: i get this error now: `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: setSpan (5 ... 5) ends beyond length 0` for this line `nameEdit.setSelection(yourFormattedString.length());`

Comment: i get error after formatting number, on this time `1,111`, repeating digits `1`